# How to save audio from 2 XLR mics as 2 separate audio files

Tags: audio

Beginner here, so I’m sorry if this is a stupid question. Trying to make a binaural asmr video. I record with 2 xlr mics, and a zoom h4n. When saving audio, it saves as one audio file, so I am unable to pan audio from each mic to either the left or right during editing. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You are recording fine. Simply split the 'stereo' file into two individual mono tracks when editing. Then, you will be able to pan them independently.

Answer (score 1):

If you record in stereo then it saves as a single file but that file is a two track stereo file containing the left and the right channels. Make sure you have it recording in stereo mode and that the microphones are placed in the correct position for binaural recording. If you need to edit further then do as mark said.